# Default_Schema not working

Tags: sql-server

I have the default schema for my user `XYZCORP\JShmoe` set to 'accounting'.
When I log as `XYZCORP\JShmoe` and execute `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()` it returns **"dbo"** instead of **'accounting'**.

Consequentially this works:

```
Select * From accounting.UserInfo
```

but this doesn't:

```
Select * From UserInfo
```

`XYZCORP\JShmoe` is not sysadmin.

As a note, the above is on our production server.
On our dev server everything seems to be the same (all the login and user properties I can see) but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

As you're finding, default_schema is kind of fragile. My recommendation would be to not rely on that mechanism for object resolution but rather to fully qualify your objects (e.g. accounting.UserInfo instead of UserInfo). That said...

Here are a couple of situations that could explain what you're seeing:

- The user is a member of the sysadmin group. According to the documentation, members of sysadmin always get dbo as their default schema regardless of database ownership. Check the sys.login_token view to confirm or deny this
- The user is a member of a Windows group that is itself a database principal (i.e. has an entry in sys.database_principals) and has a default_schema set. The documentation is clear about how resolution works here as well: if a user belongs to such a group, that group's default schema is used. If a user belongs to multiple such groups, the default_schema for group with *the lowest principal id* is used (emphasis mine). So, even if you have the same groups between your dev and production servers, if they were created *in a different order*, your results will be different between the two environments. Check the sys.user_token view to see what group memberships the current user has.

So, assuming that you can't take my initial advice of fully qualifying your objects, check the two conditions above.

Comment: Thanks much for the quick and clear response. The user is not a sysadmin as I mentioned but I'll check windows/AD groups and see if it resolved the issue. I usually qualify the objects in my queries but this is for a user which writes her own queries and is annoyed by the need to qualify. She is also the one signing my checks... ;o)

Comment: "Trust but verify" on the sysadmin issue. A quick look at sys.login_token will make sure she isn't getting it from an AD group or something crazy.